# Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context In React-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using a react-select component. It is generating multiple  elements in my source page which is messing with my SEO. Does anyone knows how can I stop these style tags from generating inside of my div.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKCqJ.png)]

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5WNc.png)]

You can see the images above. for reference

Did some Research did not find anything useful.